# supervising a number of existing processes

Tags: process, elixir, erlang-supervisor

In elixir, is there any way of supervising existing processes?
Like

```
Supervisor.supervise_processes([pid1,pid2,...,pidn],strategy: :simple_one_for_one)
```

Comment: I don't see how Supervisor can possibly restart the process when it exits (I believe this is what you want since you mentioned `:simple_one_for_one`) from just the pid of an existing process. It doesn't know the function that spawned it or the arguments that were used to spawn the function.

Comment: OK thanks, that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't. Supervisors take *specifications* of processes, not processes, so they can reuse the specification over and over again to restart the process. Clearly, a process id alone is not enough data to do a restart when it dies.

Having said that - you can [monitor](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Process.html#monitor/1) a process and do whatever you want when you get a signal that it died.